# postgres backup script not as postgres user

Tags: postgresql, shell, pg-dump

I want to create a postgres backup script but I don't want to use the postgres user because the unix system I am in has few restrictions. What I want to do is run this script as a regular user of the unix system (network) on a crontab and use database admin account in the script.

Just to make it clear in the unix system (network) I have user `foo`, now we have `postgres` user who is default postgres user, and then for the database we have a database admin user `my_db_admin`. I script to execute as network user `foo` using `my_db_admin` user and credentials in the script.

This is what I started with but the problem is when I execute the script it gives an error saying password was not provided.

```
#!/bin/bash
export PASSWORD="MyPassword"
backup_dir="/BACKUP/LOCATION"
# name of the backup file has the date
backup_date=`date +%d-%m-%Y`
# only keep the backup for 30 days (maintain low storage)
number_of_days=30
pg_dump -Fc -Umy_db_admin MyDatabase -w > $backup_dir\_$backup_date
find $backup_dir -type f -prune -mtime +$number_of_days -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Here is the error:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "MyDatabase" failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Comment: Where do you supply that `PASSWORD` to `pg_dump`?

Comment: @MilenA.Radev I guess I am not sure how I can put that in pg_dump

Comment: Well, reading [the](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) [fine](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html) [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html) is a good start.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute PostgreSQL script-file from command line without userinput / password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039499/how-to-execute-postgresql-script-file-from-command-line-without-userinput-pass)

Answer (score 13):

Use a `.pgpass` file to save a password for `pg_dump`, or set the `PGPASSWORD` environment variable. Or modify `pg_hba.conf` to allow connection without a password using `peer` authentication.

This is covered in the manual:

- [`.pgpass`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html).
- [Environment variables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html)
- [Client authentication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html)

and [a search for the error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fe_sendauth%3A+no+password+supplied%22) would've found relevant information.