# Can't create postgresql database with wix toolset

Tags: postgresql, wix

I'm trying to create a database in PostgreSQL using Wix ToolSet, but I'm always getting the error "Error -2147467259: failed to create SQL database: pontow, error detail: unknown error." when I try to create a database or the error "Failed to connect to SQL database. (-2147467259 pontow    )" when I simple try to execute a  to a existing database. I  made some research and it seems to be something with access denied, but can't get it working.

I've already tried:

- Change 'postgresql.conf' and set 'listen_address = '*'';
- Change 'pg_hba.conf' and add the line 'host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust';
- PostgreSQL v9.6 and v11.2;
- Give full permissions to "Everyone" to the PosgreSQL folder and subfolders;
- Use Wix 'sql:SqlDatabase' SQL Authentication and Windows Authentication;

I'm using Windows 10 x64, Wix ToolSet v3.11.

My Product.wsx file:

```
    <Binary Id="CreateTable" SourceFile=".\CreateTable.sql"/>
    <Property Id="SQLUSERNAME" Secure="yes">postgres</Property>
    <Property Id="SQLPASSWORD" Secure="yes">test</Property>
    <Property Id="SQLSERVER" Secure="yes">localhost</Property>
    <Property Id="SQLSERVERPORT" Secure="yes">5432</Property>
    <Property Id="DATABASE_NAME" Secure="yes">pontow</Property>

    <util:User Id="SQLUser" Name="[SQLUSERNAME]" Password="[SQLPASSWORD]" />
```

```
    <Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
      <Directory Id='ProgramFilesFolder' Name='PFiles'>
        <Directory Id='InstallDir' Name='Test'>

          <Component Id="SqlComponent" Guid="35e0e97e-cdce-428b-b553-d82fadf56b28" KeyPath="yes">

            <sql:SqlDatabase Id="SqlDatabase" Database="[DATABASE_NAME]" User="SQLUser"
                             Server="[SQLSERVER],[SQLSERVERPORT]" CreateOnInstall="yes" DropOnUninstall="yes" ContinueOnError="no">
              <sql:SqlScript Id="CreateTable" BinaryKey="CreateTable" ContinueOnError="no" ExecuteOnInstall="yes"/>
            </sql:SqlDatabase>
          </Component>

        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

    <Feature Id='SqlFeature' Title='SqlFeature' Level='1'>
      <ComponentRef Id='SqlComponent' />
    </Feature>
```

I expect to create a PosgreSQL database using Wix Toolset or any suggestions to create a database from the Setup.exe would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WixSqlExtension` supports SQL Server only, not PostgreSQL.

Comment: Ouch.. Do you know any other tool or suggestion I can use to create a PostgreSQL database from the installer?

Comment: Nothing for WiX. But see other PostgreSQL posts on SO, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039499/how-to-execute-postgresql-script-file-from-command-line-without-userinput-pass.

Comment: It's often better to defer SQL configuration until after the installation.  What kind of app is this?