# How do I connect my Postgresql server with the website that I created via Wix?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, web, velo

I just created a website with Wix.com. For the project that I am working on, I need to use my Postgresql database server with that website that I made. Do you have any idea about how to do it?

Comment: Apparently [you can't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55763634/13860).

Comment: Does anyone know that it is possible now?